# Unable to load raster data from PostGIS database into GRASS GIS

Tags: postgis, raster, grass-gis

I have a PostGIS (PostgreSQL 10.8) database with vector and raster data that I have connected to GRASS (7.8). I have successfully loaded my vector data into GRASS from the PostGIS database but have not been able to figure out how to do the same for the raster data. Does anyone have experience with this or know the commands might be?

Comment: AFAIK there is no support for PostGIS Raster data, but r.import might be able to read it (through GDAL).

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for loading raster data:

```
r.in.gdal input="PG:dbname=db port=5432 user=username password=password table=YourRaster mode=2" output=outputRast
```